# jQuery.animate() does not do the first animation properly

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with a slideshow I'm writing. The problem is that I have an animation that runs every time an slide is changed. It works fine every time but the first, that it just changed without the animation.

Reducing the problem, it's something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pyriku/XYLCH/. The blocks should moved slowly, but the first time each block moves, it does inmidietly.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has something to do with the first selected square having its `top` property set by a CSS selector. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XYLCH/2/

I removed the `.selected` selector in your CSS and added `style="top: 50px;"` as an attribute to the first div. I also added `top: 10px` to the `.squares` selector in CSS to prevent the squares from jumping around the first time through.

The problem is: you are adding the `.selected` class to the square that is about to move, which sets the `top` property to `50px`. Then you try to animate it to `top: 50px`, but it's already there because of when you added the `.selected` class.

Comment: Thanks! It was the solution and worked fine at the real problem.